# What is the meaning of " carrying with it" in this text?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning, phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

Repeatedly attacked by Parthia and Persia, it had never fallen; but once, after which it had been soon recovered; and now for many years it had come to be regarded as the bulwark of the Roman power in the East, and as carrying with it the dominion of Western asia.

https://www.gutenberg.org/files/16167/16167-h/16167-h.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The city that was repeatedly attacked by Parthia and Persia, Nisibus, was "regarded as the bulwark of the Roman power". By "carrying with it the dominion of Western Asia", the author means that the city was a central element of the Romans' power over Western Asia. It's a sort of metaphor: the city "contained" or "carried" their power/dominion.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. What part of speech is it in this sentence, you mean? It's a present progressive verb.

Comment: Is "carrying" an adjective?